# What's the purpose of the + (pos) unary operator in Python?

Tags: python

Generally speaking, what should the unary `+` do in Python?

I'm asking because, so far, I have never seen a situation like this:

```
+obj != obj
```

Where `obj` is a generic object implementing `__pos__()`.

So I'm wondering: why do `+` and `__pos__()` exist? Can you provide a real-world example where the expression above evaluates to `True`?

Comment: Possibly a useful answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748185/what-does-a-plus-sign-do-in-front-of-a-variable-in-python

Comment: Related (different language, same query): [What does the unary plus operator do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/727516/what-does-the-unary-plus-operator-do)

Comment: http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2004-September/274761.html

Comment: If anyone which knows C/C++ expects that `++variable` increments the variable, he is in for a surprise. The best thing is that it is valid python code, so it will not throw an error.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I believe that Python operators where inspired by C, where the `+` operator was introduced  for symmetry (and also some useful hacks, see comments).

In weakly typed languages such as PHP or Javascript, + tells the runtime to coerce the value of the variable into a number. For example, in Javascript:

```
   +"2" + 1
=> 3
   "2" + 1
=> '21'
```

Python is strongly typed, so strings don't work as numbers, and, as such, don't implement an unary plus operator.

It is certainly possible to implement an object for which +obj != obj :

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __pos__(self):
...        return "bar"
... 
>>> +Foo()
'bar'
>>> obj = Foo()
>>> +"a"
```

As for an example for which it actually makes sense, check out the
[surreal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surreal_number). They are a superset of the reals which includes
infinitesimal values (+ epsilon, - epsilon), where epsilon is 
a positive value which is smaller than any other positive number, but
greater than 0; and infinite ones (+ infinity, - infinity).

You could define `epsilon = +0`, and `-epsilon = -0`.

While `1/0` is still undefined, `1/epsilon = 1/+0` is `+infinity`, and `1/-epsilon` = `-infinity`. It is 
nothing more than taking limits of `1/x` as `x` aproaches `0` from the right (+) or from the left (-).

As `0` and `+0` behave differently, it makes sense that `0 != +0`.

Comment: Actually, in C the unary `+` has a use beyond symmetry. It doesn't change the value, but its presence forces the implicit conversions that happen on arithmetic (which may change the type).

Comment: That's interesting. Could you post an example?

Comment: @vklj: See e.g. http://www.verious.com/qa/does-the-unary-operator-have-any-practical-use (which also shows unary `+` being used to turn an l-value into an r-value).

Answer (score 52):

Here's a "real-world" example from the `decimal` package:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> obj = Decimal('3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971')
>>> +obj != obj  # The __pos__ function rounds back to normal precision
True
>>> obj
Decimal('3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971')
>>> +obj
Decimal('3.141592653589793238462643383')
```

Comment: I'm not Dutch, but does this seem like the obvious right way to round back to normal precision to anyone who is?

Comment: @kojiro: [yes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/347749/4279). The reason is that decimals are immutable and therefore can carry more digits than the current precision allows so to take the current context into account, you need an explicit operation that uses it and may return a new decimal e.g., `0 + obj`, `1 * obj`, `obj ** 1`, etc. btw, `localcontext()` above is unnecessary: [`+Decimal('3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971')`](http://ideone.com/Og4Brl) creates 2 decimals (1st corresponds to the given string, 2nd correspond to current precision (the result)).

Comment: The standard specification for decimal arithmetic specifies `plus` and `minus` functions that exhibit this behavior. In addition to providing those functions as part of a context, Python maps their behavior to unary `-` and `+`. See http://speleotrove.com/decimal/daops.html#refplusmin

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Thanks for pointing that out; I edited to remove the references to `localcontext`

Comment: This looks like a bug in the `decimal` package more than anything.

Answer (score 36):

In Python 3.3 and above, [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#counter-objects) uses the `+` operator to remove non-positive counts.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> fruits = Counter({'apples': 0, 'pears': 4, 'oranges': -89})
>>> fruits
Counter({'pears': 4, 'apples': 0, 'oranges': -89})
>>> +fruits
Counter({'pears': 4})
```

So if you have negative or zero counts in a `Counter`, you have a situation where `+obj != obj`.

```
>>> obj = Counter({'a': 0})
>>> +obj != obj
True
```

Comment: And similartly for `-fruits`(which gives `Counter({'oranges': 89})`).

Answer (score 15):

A lot of examples here look more like bugs. This one is actually a feature, though:

### The `+` operator implies a *copy*.

This is extremely useful when writing generic code for scalars and arrays.

For example:

```
def f(x, y):
    z = +x
    z += y
    return z
```

This function works on **both** scalars **and** NumPy arrays **without** making extra copies and **without** changing the type of the object and **without** requiring any external dependencies!

If you used `numpy.positive` or something like that, you would introduce a NumPy dependency, and you would force numbers to NumPy types, which can be undesired by the caller.

If you did `z = x + y`, your result would no longer necessarily be the same type as `x`. In many cases that's fine, but when it's not, it's not an option.

If you did `z = --x`, you would create an unnecessary copy, which is slow.

If you did `z = 1 * x`, you'd perform an unnecessary multiplication, which is also slow.

If you did `copy.copy`... I guess that'd work, but it's pretty cumbersome.

Unary `+` is a really great option for this.

Comment: Maybe to *you* it implies a copy. It's not at all obvious that is *should*, and it certainly isn't supported by the things people most often try to copy: lists, dicts, sets, etc.

Comment: @chepner: I've never seen something like `+dict` work in any language for you to dispute whether it implies a copy or not... it seems like you might be confused by what "implies" means?

Comment: You are the one claiming that `+` implies a copy: on what basis?

Comment: @chepner: In a sane world `+` would do the same thing as `-` except that its return value has the opposite sign... it would be rather insane for `y = +(+x); z = -(-x); x += 1; assert(y == z)` not to hold true. Which... shouldn't exactly be shocking news. Surely you're aware that Python (and C++, etc.) as well numerous third-party libraries have been designed so that this **does** hold true. If that translates into "certainly not supported" by reality, I... don't know what to offer you.

Comment: There is a big difference between `-` and `+`: `-` *always* changes the sign of its argument; `+` would be a no-op on a value that is already positive. I have no reason to think that `+(+x)` should make even one, let alone two, copies of `x` rather than simply returning `x` itself (which is exactly what `int.__pos__` does).

Comment: @chepner: Yes, it changes its sign. That says nothing about copying. `int` is immutable and wouldn't violate that in inequality. And it's patently false that you have "no reason" to believe `+(+x)` would make a copy. It literally does so for mutable cases and you're well-aware of this. That itself gives you reasons to believe this. The fact that you're ignoring reality doesn't change it  I'm not interested in a pointless argument so this will be my last comment.

Comment: Please provide an example of an existing type that makes use of this idiom.

Answer (score 8):

For symmetry, because unary minus is an operator, unary plus must be too. In most arithmetic situations, it doesn't do anything, but keep in mind that users can define arbitrary classes and use these operators for anything they want, even if it isn't strictly algebraic.

I know it's an old thread, but I wanted to extend the existing answers to provide a broader set of examples:

- `+` could assert for positivity and throw exception if it's not - very useful to detect corner cases.
- The object may be multivalued (think `±sqrt(z)` as a single object -- for solving quadratic equations, for multibranched analytical functions, anything where you can "collapse" a twovalued function into one branch with a sign. This includes the ±0 case mentioned by vlopez.
- If you do lazy evaluation, this may create a function object that adds something to whatever it is applied to something else. For instance, if you are parsing arithmetics incrementally.
- As an identity function to pass as an argument to some functional.
- For algebraic structures where sign accumulates -- ladder operators and such. Sure, it could be done with other functions, but one could conceivably see something like `y=+++---+++x`. Even more, they don't have to commute. This constructs a free group of plus and minuses which could be useful. Even in formal grammar implementations.
- Wild usage: it could "mark" a step in the calculation as "active" in some sense. reap/sow system -- every plus remembers the value and at the end, you can gather the collected intermediates... because why not?

That, plus all the typecasting reasons mentioned by others.

And after all... it's nice to have one more operator in case you need it.

Answer (score 5):

`__pos__()` exists in *Python* to give programmers similar possibilities as in *`C++` language* — to **overload operators**, in this case the *unary operator* `+`.

(*Overloading* operators means give them a *different meaning for different objects*, e. g. *binary `+`* behaves differently for *numbers* and for *strings* — numbers are *added* while strings are *concatenated*.)

Objects may implement (beside others) these *emulating numeric types* functions (methods):

```
    __pos__(self)             # called for unary +
    __neg__(self)             # called for unary -
    __invert__(self)          # called for unary ~
```

So `+object` means the same as `object.__pos__()` — they are interchangeable.

However, `+object` is more easy on the eye.

Creator of a particular object has free hands to implement these functions as he wants — as other people showed in their real world's examples.

And my contribution — *as a joke:* `++i != +i` *in C/C++*.

Comment: `__pos__` exists because `+` does; this doesn't' explain why `+` exists in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Unary `+` is actually the fastest way to see if a value is numeric or not (and raise an exception if it isn't)!  It's a single instruction in bytecode, where something like isinstance(i, int) actually looks up and calls the `isinstance` function!

Comment: Do you have any source for this?

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/ExaGf56qM

Comment: Wow, this is enlightening! I also tested it using the `timeit` module and it's consistent with your answer.

Comment: `Counter` is not numeric but implements `+`