# what is the meaning of float.__pos__?

Tags: python

I am writing a function computing like `eval`. When I come to `float.__pos__` ,I really don't Know why there exists such a useless function. Because:

```
>>> float.__pos__(-1.0)
-1.0
>>> float.__pos__(1.0)
1.0
```

while `float.__neg__` is totally different:

```
>>> float.__neg__(1.0)
-1.0
```

So what is the meaning of `float.__pos__`?

Comment: @Doorknob Thanks. Now I know the keyword `unary`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `__pos__` method defines the effect of the unary + operator for any object.

As Tim Peters mentions, it has no effect for floats.

See [What's the purpose of the + (pos) unary operator in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16819023/whats-the-purpose-of-the-pos-unary-operator-in-python) for an example where it's used to do something.

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> help(float.__pos__)
Help on wrapper_descriptor:

__pos__(...)
    x.__pos__() <==> +x
```

It's the "unary plus" operator, invoked when you do `+x` with `x` a float.  It basically does nothing for floats, as you've discovered ;-)  However, you *could* define a subclass that did something non-trivial with it.  That's why it's there.

Comment: `a subclass that did something non-trivial with it`, something like what? I mean, what will happen if there is no __pos__

Comment: thanks. I've saw the same question and known why.

Comment: @Pythoner, see the link @DavidGinsburg posted for examples of numeric types in Python where unary plus does do something non-trivial.  If floats (or ints) didn't support `__pos__()`, the expression `+3.0` (or  `+3`) would blow up at runtime, with an `AttributeError` *looking* for `__pos__` :-)

Answer (score 1):

Python has a unary negation operator to negate numbers, as you're probably well aware:

```
>>> x = 5
>>> print(-x)
-5
>>> x = -5
>>> print(-x)
5
```

Say you're making a list of numbers, though. It might be more consistent if you prefixed the positive ones with a `+`, so Python has a unary `+` operator, too:

```
>>> numbers = [-3, -2, -1, 0, +1, +2, +3]
```

When you use the unary `+` operator on a number, you're right that it doesn't do anything; it's there just for consistency.

Now when you consider that in Python you can override operators on types, of course you'd need a `__neg__` to negate an instance of that type. Python just decided to be consistent by also having a `__pos__` to…not negate an instance of that type. `float`, like all other types overriding these operators, follow this protocol, and `float`'s implementation of `__pos__` is just the identity function.