# Why do i get error when i use x+ but not when +x in this code?

Tags: python-2.7

```
x = 2
if x == 2:
    print x
else:
    x +
```

i get error like 
print x +
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: x+ is not valid syntax. +x does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

`+x` calls [`__pos__(self)`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__pos__#object.__pos__) and is therefore a valid python statement; `x + y` is an expression that needs two operands (see [binary arithmetic expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations)); `x +` is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

This is the unary operator `+`, which is like writing `-x` but doesn't really do anything. See [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_operation) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

In `+x`, `+` is an operator that works on a single number, such as `-x` and `~x`. You can refer the bottom table on  https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html.

However, in `x +`, `+` is an operator for two numbers. In your code, the second number is not provided, so you got an error.

You can check this answer 
[What's the purpose of the + (pos) unary operator in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16819023/whats-the-purpose-of-the-pos-unary-operator-in-python) for why we need `+x` in Python.