# variable repr in python based on call depth

Tags: python, repr

I have a (bad?) habit of displaying classes in Python like structures in Matlab, where each attribute is printed along with its value in a nice clean layout. This is done by implementing the `__repr__` method in the class.

When working with objects inside of dictionaries or lists, this display style can be a bit distracting. In this case I'd like to do a more basic display.

Here's the envisioned pseudocode:

```py
def __repr__(self):
    if direct_call():
        return do_complicated_printing(self)
    else:
        #something simple that isn't a ton of lines/characters
        return type(self)
```

In this code `direct_call()` means that this isn't being called as part of another display call. Perhaps this might entail looking for `repr` in the stack? How would I implement direct call detection?

So I might have something like:

```
>>> data
<class my_class> with properties:

        a: 1
   cheese: 2
     test: 'no testing'
```

But in a list I'd want a display like:

```
>>> data2 = [data, data, data, data]
>>> data2
[<class 'my_class'>,<class 'my_class',<class 'my_class'>,<class 'my_class'>]
```

I know it is possible for me to force this type of display by calling some function that does this, but I want `my_class` to be able to control this behavior, without extra work from the user in asking for it.

In other words, this is **not** a solution:

```
>>> print_like_I_want(data2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a strange thing to want to do, and generally a function or method ought to do the same thing whoever is calling it. But in this case, `__repr__` is only meant for the programmer's convenience, so convenience seems like a good enough reason to make it work the way you're asking for.

However, unfortunately what you want isn't actually possible, because for whatever reason, the `list.__repr__` method isn't visible on the stack. I tested in Python 3.5.2 and Python 3.8.1:

```py
>>> class ReprRaises:
...     def __repr__(self):
...         raise Exception()
... 
>>> r = ReprRaises()
>>> r
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in __repr__
Exception
>>> [r]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in __repr__
Exception
```

As you can see, the stack is the same whether or not the object being `repr`'d is in a list. (The `__repr__` frame on the stack belongs to the `ReprRaises` class, not `list`.)

I also tested using [`inspect.stack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.stack):

```py
>>> import inspect
>>> class ReprPrints:
...     def __repr__(self):
...         print(*inspect.stack(), sep='\n')
...         return 'foo'
>>> r = ReprPrints()
>>> r
FrameInfo(frame=<frame object at 0x7fcbe4a38588>, filename='<stdin>', lineno=3, function='__repr__', code_context=None, index=None)
FrameInfo(frame=<frame object at 0x7fcbe44fb388>, filename='<stdin>', lineno=1, function='<module>', code_context=None, index=None)
foo
>>> [r]
FrameInfo(frame=<frame object at 0x7fcbe4a38588>, filename='<stdin>', lineno=3, function='__repr__', code_context=None, index=None)
FrameInfo(frame=<frame object at 0x7fcbe44fb388>, filename='<stdin>', lineno=1, function='<module>', code_context=None, index=None)
[foo]
```

Again, there's no visible difference in the call stack between the object itself vs. the object in a list; so there's nothing for your `__repr__` to check for.

---

So, the closest you can get is some kind of `print_like_I_want` function. This *can* at least be written in a way that lets each class define its own behaviour:

```py
def pp(obj):
    try:
        _pp = obj._pp
    except AttributeError:
        print(repr(obj))
    else:
        print(_pp())
```

The only way I can think of to do it with fewer keypresses is by overloading a unary operator, like the usually-useless [unary plus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16819023/whats-the-purpose-of-the-pos-unary-operator-in-python):

```py
>>> class OverloadUnaryPlus:
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return 'foo'
...     def __pos__(self):
...         print('bar')
... 
>>> obj = OverloadUnaryPlus()
>>> obj
foo
>>> +obj
bar
```

Comment: Interesting approach with the unary plus operator! It reminds me of the '?' help operator in R.

Answer (score 2):

`__repr__` is intended to provide a short, often programmatic display of an object. It's used as the method of choice for all built in containers to display elements. You should therefore override `__repr__` to provide your short output.

`__str__` is the function intended for the full fancy display of an object. It's what normally shows up when you `print` an object. You can also trigger it by calling `str`. You should put your long fancy output in `__str__`, not `__repr__`.

The only modification you will have to make is to explicitly call `print(obj)` or `str(obj)` rather than `repr(obj)` or just `obj` in the REPL. As [@kaya3's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60050030/2988730) shows, stack inspection won't help you much, and in my opinion would not be a clean solution even if it did.