# Why does Python treat consecutive repetitions of the addition operator as just a single repetition?

Tags: python, operators, addition

Today I noticed that the Python interpreter treats consecutive repetitions of the addition operator as just one repetition of the operator. For example:

```
>>> 1 ++ 2
3
```

Of what use was it to not simply raise an error when such an event occurs? I find it much more believable that a programmer who typed

```
>>> 1 -+-++ 2
```

was just out of their mind; it would be highly unlikely that this ever intentionally appears in code.

It seems to serve no purpose, for writing something like

```
>>> +-1
```

simply returns `-1`, demonstrating that the operation does not make the number positive, rather, it simply performs the identity operation.

Comment: ... `+(1) == 1` and `-(1) == -1`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16819023/1424875 may have some good discussion. One possible answer is that unary + and unary - are both defined for consistency/symmetry, and an added benefit is that unary + can be overridden where appropriate for certain classes.

Comment: Any excess operators found subsequently will be treated as [unary operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#unary-arithmetic-and-bitwise-operations) for the next value - there's actually one more, the inverse `~` operator, so the expression `-+~1` is also valid.  They are backed by underlying operator methods [`__pos__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.pos) for `+`, [`__neg__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.__neg__) for `-`, and [`__invert__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.__invert__) for `~`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's overloaded. It's the addition operator (implemented by the [`__add__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__add__) method), and also the [unary](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#unary-arithmetic-and-bitwise-operations) positive operator (implemented by [`__pos__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__pos__)). Compare that to `-`, which is the subtraction operator ([`__sub__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__sub__)) and unary negative operator ([`__neg__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__neg__)).

So for example, `1 ++ 2` is parsed as `1 + (+ 2)` which simplifies down to `1 + 2` for integers, but not necessarily for other types. See [What's the purpose of the + (pos) unary operator in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16819023/4518341)

Answer (score 0):

It's mathematical. While it doesn't make sense to a normal person, to python +(+1) and -(-1) is +, +(-1) and -(+1) is -.
Jumping back into the question, it isn't just python that does this. It's mathematical thinking. It's like telling a computer a variable called string is equal to 29. It sounds wrong but the computer thinks it is normal.