# Use cases of `numpy.positive`

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ufunc

There is a `positive` function in `numpy` (version 1.13+), which seemingly does nothing:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np                                                                               

In [2]: A = np.array([0, 1, -1, 1j, -1j, 1+1j, 1-1j, -1+1j, -1-1j, np.inf, -np.inf])                     

In [3]: A == np.positive(A)                                                                              
Out[3]: 
array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True])
```

The documentation says: `` Returned array or scalar: `y = +x` ``

What are the use cases of this function?

Comment: It is the [unary + (plus) operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#unary-arithmetic-and-bitwise-operations).  See, for example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16819023/whats-the-purpose-of-the-pos-unary-operator-in-python and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748185/what-does-a-plus-sign-do-in-front-of-a-variable-in-python.

Comment: The doc also says _Equivalent to `x.copy()`, but only defined for types that support arithmetic._. I guess that's it, that look pretty useless

Comment: Searched GitHub with `"np.positive" extension:.py language:Python` and there are a lot of hits - many false hits.  Sorting it by `reently indexed` brought some to the top: those look like there being used in unittests.

Comment: Can it be used to convert everything to numbers?

Comment: @cglacet why does someone might want to use `np.positive` for the purpose of copying, if he has an explicit `np.copy`? (Apart from the fact that  `np.positive` is a `ufunc` which means it is written in C.) For me it would look like a bad code style.

Comment: @SergeyKirienko Nope.

Comment: It's probably there for completeness.  You might want to apply `np.negative` to some arrays, and `np.positive` to others, both with the same set of added parameters (`order`, `casting` etc).  You probably wouldn't use it plain and in isolation, but as part of larger code it might be useful.  Why are we allowed to write `+12.34` when `12.34` is just as good?  Why does Python define a `pass` that does nothing?

Answer (score 1):

There are likely very few use-cases for this function. It is provided because every python operator is exposed as a ufunc in numpy:

- Unary `+`: `np.positive`
- Unary `-`: `np.negative`
- Binary `+`: `np.add`
- Binary `-`: `np.subtract`
- etc ...

As the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.positive.html) states, and noted in the other answer, `np.positive` makes a copy of the data, just as `np.copy` does, but with two caveats:

1. It can change the `dtype` of the input
2. It is only defined for arithmetic types. If you attempt to call it on a boolean array, for example, you will get

   ```
    UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'positive' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('bool') -> dtype('bool')
   ```

One other thing, is that since `positive` is a `ufunc`, it can work in-place, making it an effective no-op function for arithmetic types:

```
np.positive(x, out=x)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have a vector `x`, then `np.positive(x)` gives you, `+1*(x)` and `np.negative(x)` gives you `-1*(x)`.

```
np.positive([-1,0.7])

output: array([-1. ,  0.7])


np.negative([-1.5,0.7])

output:array([ 1.5, -0.7])


np.positive(np.array([0, 1, -1, 1j, -1j, 1+1j, 1-1j, -1+1j, -1-1j, np.inf, -np.inf]))

output: array([  0.+0.j,   1.+0.j,  -1.+0.j,   0.+1.j,  -0.-1.j,   1.+1.j,
         1.-1.j,  -1.+1.j,  -1.-1.j,  inf+0.j, -inf+0.j])


np.negative(np.array([0, 1, -1, 1j, -1j, 1+1j, 1-1j, -1+1j, -1-1j, np.inf, -np.inf]))

output: array([ -0.-0.j,  -1.-0.j,   1.-0.j,  -0.-1.j,   0.+1.j,  -1.-1.j,
        -1.+1.j,   1.-1.j,   1.+1.j, -inf-0.j,  inf-0.j])
```

Use Case depends though. Once use case its an alternative of `x1 = copy(x)`. Its creates an duplicate array for your use.

Comment: If you wanted a copy, you could have just done `x.copy()`, or `+x` if you really want to be confusing.

Comment: I know. `ndarray.copy` is faster than this operation. One thing is different in this. Its supports `dtype`. whereas copy doesn't support. So there can be some of the implications while writing complex math algorithm. You can check the details [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.positive.html?highlight=positive#numpy.positive).

Comment: You should use `copy` where just you want to make a duplicate. But doing some mathematical operation, if you want to copy as well want to take advantage of casting, order and other stuff. Then only you should go for this.